# encoding filter , struts working just when using html:form tag

Tags: html, encoding, filter, struts

I face this problem. I have a filter that sets the character encoding of the request according to the filter's config (for example, to UTF-8). This works with forms coded using the struts html:form tag. However, if I use the ordinary HTML form tag, the data are not encoded correctly.

This is the filter definition in the web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>EncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Here's the filter :

```
public class EncodingFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
private String encoding;
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.encoding = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
}
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

Comment: Is your page content-type charset set to UTF-8? Are you using POST or GET? Have you looked at the page source to see the difference between the struts-tag generated form and the standard HTML one?

Comment: the problem is resolved by specifying method='post' it works, html:form is transformed into form witch method is post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a Struts tag `<html:form>` and omit the METHOD attribute it defaults to POST.
If you use a standard HTML `<form>` and omit the METHOD attribute it defaults to GET.

Tomcat will process your POST and GET parameters differently:

**POST:** your filter will be used. Note that you should really only set the request character encoding if it has not been specified by the client (your filter is always setting it to UTF-8). Tomcat comes with a filter SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java that does this.

**GET**: Tomcat will use ISO-8859-1 as the default character encoding. There are two ways to specify how GET parameters are interpreted:

- Set the URIEncoding attribute on the  element in server.xml to something specific (e.g. URIEncoding="UTF-8").
- Set the useBodyEncodingForURI attribute on the  element in server.xml to true. This will cause the Connector to use the request body's encoding for GET parameters.

This is all in: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Comment: thank you , it's very clear and that's what i was looking for for several days :)